# What are the input parameters of VASP for 2D material geometry optimization?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, geometry-optimization

Apparently, my input parameters are not good for geometry relaxation of 2D materials using `VASP`.

```
EDIFFG = 1E-2
ISMEAR = 0
SIGMA = 0.05

ENCUT = 337

NSW = 100
ISIF = 3
IBRION = 2

#SCAN-RVV10
METAGGA  = SCAN
LUSE_VDW = .TRUE.
BPARAM = 15.7
LASPH = .TRUE.

NPAR = 32
KPAR = 12
```

What am I doing wrong? Is ISIF=3 not a good idea for 2D materials? Or is it impossible to use implemented geometry optimization procedures for 2D materials with `VASP`?

Comment: You can't use ISIF=3 for 2D materials. This question is answered by this post: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2022/geometry-optimization-for-n-layers-in-vasp/2023#2023

Answer (score 3):

Fix c-axis and ISIF = 3 can be used to optimize monolayer.

how to fix c-axis see following link:
https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/4656/3331